# How can I get the local Storage Value

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
var cookieValue = document.getElementById("demo");      
var value = cookieValue .getAttribute('value');

if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
{
  alert(value);
  localStorage.setItem = ("GetData" , value);
  alert(localStorage.setItem);
}

function loading()
{
  alert("coming");
  var allcookies = localStorage.getItem('GetData');
  alert(allcookies);
}
```

Above is the way I am setting `localStorage.setItem` and I am getting LocalStorage.
But Where I didn't get the output it is showing Null. Please Suggest me any Solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code should be :

```
var cookieValue = document.getElementById("demo");      
    var value = cookieValue .getAttribute('value');
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
    {
        alert(value);
        localStorage.setItem("GetData" , value);
        alert(localStorage.getItem("GetData"));

    }

function loading()
{
        alert("coming");
        var allcookies = localStorage.getItem('GetData');
        alert(allcookies);

}
```

OR

```
var cookieValue = document.getElementById("demo");      
    var value = cookieValue .getAttribute('value');
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
    {
        alert(value);
        localStorage["GetData"] = value;
        alert(localStorage["GetData"]);

    }

function loading()
{
        alert("coming");
        var allcookies = localStorage["GetData"];
        alert(allcookies);

}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please select the accepted answer icon at the left of the answer which has help you the most in order to help future users finding directly the right anwser without reading all answers.

Comment: your `getitem(` and `setitem(` needs to be `getItem(` and 'setItem(`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for `setItem` is

> localStorage.setItem("GetData", value)

not

> localStorage.setItem = ("GetData", value)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if( window.localStorage ) {
    alert(value);
    localStorage.setItem("GetData" , value);
}
```